# Merge candidate branch in origin/master to master in Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio

Here is a screen shot of the branches for a repo from Visual Studio's Git Repo pane

[image: Branches]

For a task a branch was created from master (the one with green arrow) and after the PR it got merged into 'candidate' in 'remote/origin'

Now how to merge the candidate into master(the one with green arrow below the Repo symbol at the top).

Here are the options on master(green)

[image]

Options on master(blue)

[image]

Options for candidate blue

[image]

New Git user here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Without asking about the strategy you're following in your team.. I wonder why the option **merge origin/candidate into master** is disabled! You could

1. Restart Visual Studio and wait untill no background processes are there.
2. Right click on local master -> fetch and wait.
3. Right click on Remote candidate -> merge origin/candidate into master -> Ok.

Note: keep an eye on output window in visual studio -> select 'Source Control - Git' to see git commands output.

Comment: This is exactly my thought as well. The key here is figuring out why in the third screenshot, the Merge option is grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout master (according to your screenshot you already have).
Then pull origin/candidate into master.

I guess usually you would wait for the remote master to merge candidate and then pull origin/master into master and for the time being you would checkout origin/candidate so your local branch names match the remote branch names. At least that would cause less confusion for me.

Comment: tried "git pull origin candidate:master" from Git Bash as could not figure out how to do this from VS and this is the message from CLI "[rejected]        candidate  -> master  (non-fast-forward)"